# Installing IJulia

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

When I try to install IJulia from Julia terminal using the following commands:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

I get the following error:

```
SystemError: opening file "C:\\Users\\lenovo\\.julia\\registries\\General\\Registry.toml": No such file or directory
```

How may I fix this?

Comment: You probably have a corrupted registry. You can try to delete `C:\\Users\\lenovo\\.julia\\registries` and try again. That should re-download the registry.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the registry by doing: `registry rm General` and then try running: `registry add https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General` in the Package Manager which can be accessed by entering `]` into the repl.

See the Registry docs for reference: https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/registries/#Adding-registries-1